# AngularJs Group By Data and Display Using Filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have the following object and want to create a filter to group by ParentCategoryID.

```
[
{id : 116, Desciption : 'Item1', ParentID : 1, parent : 'Parent1'},
{id : 117, Desciption : 'Item2', ParentID : 2, parent : 'Parent2'},
{id : 118, Desciption : 'Item3', ParentID : 2, parent : 'Parent2'},
{id : 119, Desciption : 'Item4', ParentID : 1, parent : 'Parent1'}
]
```

so the outcome would be

```
Parent1
  Item1
  Item4
Parent2
  Item2
  Item3
```

my filter currently looks like this:

```
productDetailsApp.filter('groupBy', function() {
    return function(list, group_by) {       
        var filtered = [];
        var prev_item = null;

        angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
            if (prev_item !== null) {
                if (prev_item[group_by] === item[group_by]) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                } 
            }

            prev_item = item;
        });

        console.log(filtered);
        return filtered;
    };

});
```

and html :

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="d in details | groupBy:'ParentID'">
            <h2 >{{d.parent}}</h2>           
            <li>{{d.Desciption}}</li>
  </div>
```

But this outputs only outputs the last element as prev_item for first item always will be null :

```
Parent1
  Item4
Parent2
  Item3
```

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well semantically it would make a lot more sense to re-arrange your data. into something like this.

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Parent 1',
        items: [
            {id: 126, description: 'Item 1'},
            {....}
        ]
    }
]
```

and then using nested repeats. This data structure more accurately describes the actual situation and will make your life easier. If re-arranging the data is not an option or you don't understand nested ng-repeats let me know and we can find an alternative.